# How to convert an Epoch timestamp to a Date in Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I didn't find any simple answer to this while I was looking around, so I thought I'd put it up here in case anyone was having the same problem as me with what should have been a trivial issue.

I was using ReDash analytics with Google's BigQuery and had turned on [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) in the datasource settings. For the purposes of my query, I needed to convert a timestamp - unix time in milliseconds, as a string - to a Date format so that I could use the DATE_DIFF method.

As an example... `"1494865480000"` to `"2017-05-15"`

The difficulty was that casting and conversion was excessively strict and there seemed no adequate way to make it parse. See my answer down below!
(Though let me know if some SQL sensei knows a more eloquent way!)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Do you mind setting up your post as both a question and an answer, though? You can post an answer to your own question. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](How to ask) or check some of the other questions and answers under the google-bigquery tag for examples.

Comment: Sure thing. Done!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Standard SQL use `TIMESTAMP_MICROS` function together with `EXTRACT(DATE FROM <timestamp>)`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1494865480000))
```

Comment: Needed to cast the string as INT64 first.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way with TIMESTAMP_MILLIS():

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST("1494865480000" AS INT64)))

2017-05-15
```

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, this was my solution:

`DATE_ADD( DATE'1970-01-01', INTERVAL CAST( ( CAST( epochTimestamp AS INT64 ) / 86400000 ) AS INT64 ) DAY ) AS convertedDate`

That is, I took the string, cast it to an integer, divided it by the number of milliseconds in a day, then used a DATE_ADD method, and added the result to the start of Epoch time, and calculated the resulting day.

I hope this saves another junior some time!

Answer (score 0):

Use `UTC_USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
select UTC_USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(postedon * 1000)
```

You can then extract the date using `date()`:

```
select DATE(UTC_USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(postedon * 1000))
```

This doesn't require knowing the internal format of Unix timestamps.

Comment: `UTC_USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP` doesn't seem to be available in [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators)

Comment: `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS()` in #standardSQL, see new answer