# Unix time to datetime google bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to transfer a postgres query to Google BigQuery but I can't seem to find out how to transfer this part:

```
date_trunc('Month',to_timestamp(created_utc))
```

I've tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983093/how-to-convert-an-epoch-timestamp-to-a-date-in-standard-sql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it turns the unix timestamp into 1970-01-01 instead of what the real timestamp should be (2014-etc-etc ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
DATE_TRUNC(DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)), MONTH)
```

example to test / play with

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)), MONTH)
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_08`
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Works with the legacy sql option off

Comment: sure. as mentioned in answer  - it is for BigQuery Standard SQL. If answer helped - please consider voting up - this increase your own reputation score and at the same time keep us motivated to answer your next questions :o) please consider!

Comment: Didn't think I had enough reputation. By the way, there doesn't seem to be a way to check how much of the 1 tb of data used for the trial (without some other software)?

Comment: are you saying you cannot vote because you don't have enough reputation yet? just curious

Comment: I was able to vote, it was the downvotes that confused me